# How can I fix the cursor problem in text editor

Tags: angularjs, text-editor

I am working on text editor if I enter a word with wrong spellings. whenever I correct the misspelled word and I am on current position where I am fixing the spelling mistake after removing one letter of misspelled word it took me back again to the previous position or you can say at the end of the statement. How can I fix this problem?

```
public moveCaret(win, chars) {
    var sel, range;
    // word_count chars
    sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel) {
        sel = win.getSelection();
        if (sel.character > 0) {
            var word_count = sel.focusNode;
            var newOffset = sel.focusOffset + chars;
            sel.collapse(word_count, Math.min(word_count.length, newOffset));
            console.log(newOffset, 'new')
        }
    } else if ( (sel = win.document.selection) ) {
        if (sel.type != "Control") {
            range = sel.createRange();
            range.move("character", chars);
            range.select();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: No idea what you are doing in your code, since you didn't provide it, so there's no way to give a fix; but seeing `jQuery` and `Angularjs` tags together, I'm not surprised you're having problems.....

Comment: I have shared a piece of code please have a look into it. Please guide me properly. Thanks

Comment: The problem is, since Angular regenerates the view when data changes, the textarea also gets regenerated, so the cursor doesn't keep the position it was at. This is a notoriously hard problem with textareas and editable divs in Angular. I for one have never been able to properly solve it...

Comment: I got it by the way any helpful material can you please share either in Javascript or Angular?

Comment: "any helpful material"? :) Yes, there's plenty of helpful material, tutorials and courses all over the place on Youtube, Udemy and millions of tech websites!